# Azure DevOps API get status of previous release task

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone know the api to get the status of the individual release task in a release?

[image]

I can get the status of the release itself but not the individual release tasks (PowerShell tasks in my case).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
Also if anyone knows where the source code is for ADO built in tasks condition. can you please share the link?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know the api to get the status of the individual release task in a release?

**Method 1**: You can use a REST API that is not documented：

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/attempts/{attemptId}/timelines/{timelineId}/tasks
```

It returns a brief overview and status(succeeded, inProgress, pending, failed...) of all tasks in the release.

The response body looks like the following example:

```
{
    "count": 9,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "timelineRecordId": "d81751cc-e42f-407a-9091-f611d37df33b",
            "name": "Initialize job",
            "dateStarted": "2021-04-27T06:01:21.5233333Z",
            "dateEnded": "2021-04-27T06:01:23.32Z",
            "startTime": "2021-04-27T06:01:21.5233333Z",
            "finishTime": "2021-04-27T06:01:23.32Z",
            "status": "succeeded",
            "rank": 1,
            "lineCount": 121,
            "issues": [],
            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/6/environments/6/deployPhases/6/tasks/4/logs"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "timelineRecordId": "68716c38-638d-551b-6964-2da9e273edef",
            "name": "Command Line Script",
            "dateStarted": "2021-04-27T06:01:23.33Z",
            "dateEnded": "2021-04-27T06:01:28.5833333Z",
            "startTime": "2021-04-27T06:01:23.33Z",
            "finishTime": "2021-04-27T06:01:28.5833333Z",
            "status": "succeeded",
            "rank": 2,
            "lineCount": 15,
            "issues": [],
            "task": {
                "id": "d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9",
                "name": "CmdLine",
                "version": "2.182.0"
            },
            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
            "logUrl": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/6/environments/6/deployPhases/6/tasks/5/logs"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "timelineRecordId": "fced85f1-31cf-59f2-d2e0-ccd1645b2427",
            "name": "Command Line Script",
            "dateStarted": "2021-04-27T06:01:28.5866667Z",
            "startTime": "2021-04-27T06:01:28.5866667Z",
            "status": "inProgress",
            "percentComplete": 0,
            "rank": 3,
            "issues": [],
            "task": {
                "id": "d9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9",
                "name": "CmdLine",
                "version": "2.182.0"
            },
            "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
            "logUrl": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**Method 2**: You can use the REST API [Releases - Get Task Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20task%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{releaseDeployPhaseId}/tasks/{taskId}/logs?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

It returns the running log of a specific task.

The response body looks like the following example:

```
2021-04-27T05:50:50.3443852Z ##[section]Starting: Command Line Script
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4313144Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4313918Z Task         : Command line
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4314555Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4314878Z Version      : 2.182.0
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4315342Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4315927Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2021-04-27T05:50:50.4316336Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-27T05:50:53.2219858Z Generating script.
2021-04-27T05:50:53.2572235Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-04-27T05:50:53.2972287Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\fda7641b-b8a2-4d04-8f83-94f5eda9c3b6.cmd""
2021-04-27T05:50:53.3085688Z Write your commands here
2021-04-27T05:50:53.3086888Z Hello world
2021-04-27T05:50:53.3788822Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

> If anyone knows where the source code is for ADO built in tasks condition.

I don't think Azure DevOps built-in tasks have conditions source code, because conditions can be used not only for built-in tasks, but for other tasks, jobs, stages, etc... It is supported by YAML Schema and Azure DevOps classic UI pipeline, but it has nothing to do with specific tasks.

Click [this github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) for Azure DevOps built-in task source code.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your PowerShell tasks is an environment; therefore, you can access through the `environments` that is returned by "Get Release" API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#releaseenvironment